# Edge problem: height 100% in CSS grid cell getting value of 100% width

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, css-grid

I'm trying to use CSS grid to vertically and horizontally center some text in a header/title area, and have that area (and the whole layout) be somewhat flexible/responsive.

I've set up a simple example in this [code pen](https://codepen.io/dylancristy/pen/wvvPwEQ), but if you don't want to head over there, the HTML and CSS in the example are this:

```
<div class='layout'>
  <div class='titleArea'>
    <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid meet'>
      <text x='50%' y='60%' textAnchor='middle' dy='0.07em' class='titleText'>
        Hello World
      </text>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class='mainArea'>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this:

```
.layout {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: minmax(80px, 1fr) minmax(200px, 3fr);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(80px, 1fr) minmax(200px, 3fr);
}
.titleArea {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;

  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;

  svg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* uncomment line below to see text centering work in Edge */
    /* max-height: 80px; */
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
  }
}
.titleText {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
.mainArea {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

The centering and flexing don't *quite* work in the pen, but it's pretty close, and certainly if viewed in Edge the problem becomes readily apparent.

If I open some dev tools and go and look at what's happening, the `height: 100%` is getting calculated not as the height of the parent container, but matches what's calculated for the `width: 100%`, which makes the text render huge and it completely breaks out of the parent container.  If I set a `max-height` value to something within the range of what I expect the flexing to be, it reins everything in and the text ends up where it should, but then it's frozen at that size and doesn't subtly shrink/grow as the viewport changes.

Is there some workaround for this, or is this a legitimate bug in Edge?

The above setup works just fine in Chrome, Firefox, and even IE 11, the issue is *only* with Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced this problem on my machine, it seems that the issue is related to the SVG  element's `x` and `y` attribute, it will set the starting point of the text baseline based on the whole page, instead of the SVG element. It can be possible that it is some kind of bug or it is Edge default behavior. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue.

As a workaround, I suggest you could try to change the [CSS units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp), such as 'px'. And you could modify your code as below:

```
<style>
    .layout {
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: -ms-grid;
        display: grid;
        -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
        -ms-grid-rows: minmax(80px, 1fr) minmax(200px, 3fr);
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: minmax(80px, 1fr) minmax(200px, 3fr);
    }

    .titleArea {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        width: 100%;
        -ms-grid-row: 1;
        display: -ms-grid;
        display: grid;
        -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
        -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        text-align: center;
    }

        .titleArea svg {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            /* uncomment line below to see text centering work in Edge */
            /* max-height: 80px; */
            justify-self: center;
            align-self: center;
            -ms-grid-column: 1;
            -ms-grid-row: 1;
        }

    .titleText {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .mainArea {
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
</style>
<div class='layout'>
    <div class='titleArea'>
        <svg width="100%" height="100" preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid meet'>
            <text x='50%' y='50' textAnchor='middle' dy='0.07em' class='titleText'>
                Hello World
            </text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class='mainArea'>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result as below (using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.387.0 version):

[image]